# How do I configure Jasypt to use a ZeroSaltGenerator?

Tags: grails, salt, jasypt

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 with Jasypt and I have the below in my Config.groovy:

```
jasypt {
    algorithm = "PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES"
    password = "password"
    keyObtentionIterations = 1
    saltSizeBytes = 0
}
```

How can I set the salt property to `ZeroSaltGenerator`?

Answer (score 1):

In Config.groovy, change your config for jasypt to:

```
jasypt {
    algorithm = "PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES"
    password = "password"
    keyObtentionIterations = 1
    saltGenerator = new org.jasypt.salt.ZeroSaltGenerator()
}
```

Comment: Tried  saltGenerator = new org.jasypt.salt.ZeroSaltGenerator()  , however is still generting the random  data for domain values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ZeroSaltGenerator then you have to make following changes:
Inside your config.groovy:

```
jasypt {
    encryptorRegisteredName = "gormEncryptor"
}
```

And in your resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    hibernateStringEncryptor(HibernatePBEStringEncryptor) { 
        registeredName = "gormEncryptor" 
        algorithm = "PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES"            
        password = "password"
        keyObtentionIterations = 1
        saltGenerator = new org.jasypt.salt.ZeroSaltGenerator()
    }
}
```

And it will generate the same encrypted values everytime.